# Trying to use if statements to determine a grade

Tags: java

Create a project that will allow the user to enter a number 0-100. This number will then be used to determine the person's grade. However,  what if the user does not enter a grade or the grade is greater than 100?

I have tried several different coding options

```
    private void DetemineGrade() {
    // Determines the grade

    String strOutputLine;
    String strGrade;

    // Number Formatting
    NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();

    nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
    nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);

    dblPointsTotal = Double.parseDouble(txtTotal.getText());

    strGrade = this.txtTotal.getText();
    if (strGrade == null || strGrade.trim().equals(""))
    {
        strOutputLine = ("A grade needs to be entered");
        this.txtMessage.setText(strOutputLine);
    }
    else if (dblPointsTotal < 60)
    {
        strOutputLine = ("Your grade is an F");
        this.txtMessage.setText(strOutputLine);
    }   
    else if (dblPointsTotal < 70)
    {
        strOutputLine = ("Your grade is a D");
        this.txtMessage.setText(strOutputLine);
    }       
    else if (dblPointsTotal < 80)
    {
        strOutputLine = ("Your grade is a C");
        this.txtMessage.setText(strOutputLine);
    }           
    else if (dblPointsTotal < 90)
    {
        strOutputLine = ("Your grade is a B");
        this.txtMessage.setText(strOutputLine);
    }               
    else if (dblPointsTotal >= 90)
    {
        strOutputLine = ("Your grade is an A");
        this.txtMessage.setText(strOutputLine);
    }
```

I am getting an error and the program will not run ever since inputting these lines of code 
        `strGrade = this.txtTotal.getText();
        if (strGrade == null || strGrade.trim().equals(""))
        {
            strOutputLine = ("A grade needs to be entered");
            this.txtMessage.setText(strOutputLine);
        }

This is the error that I receive

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-1" java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Unknown Source)
at DetermineGrade.DetemineGrade(DetermineGrade.java:100)
at DetermineGrade.actionPerformed(DetermineGrade.java:79)
at java.awt.Button.processActionEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Button.processEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: As the error says, you're passing an empty string to `parseDouble` at `Double.parseDouble(txtTotal.getText())`, and an empty string can't be parsed as a number.

Comment: You're checking if the empty is empty __after__ you already tried to convert it. You should convert it only when you're sure the input is not empty.

Comment: So now I have everything working except that it still gives the same error. Where should I have the part with the strGrade in it so that dblPointsTotal is not checking if the empty is empty. Sorry I am new to java and I still have a lot of questions about certain things in code

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try using exception handling so if an invalid "number" is entered (or not entered at all), the program will catch the exception and tell the user that their input (or lack of an input) is invalid. (See [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble(java.lang.String)) for the API).